# On what basis could the Federal Government legalize abortions?

Tags: united-states, abortion

Now that Roe vs. Wade is expected to be overturned, many politicians are calling for [legislation to protect the right to an abortion](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2022/05/03/abortion-roe-wade-codify-bernie-biden/) to be passed on the federal level. But on what grounds could the federal government legalize abortions in all 50 states? Would they be forced to open federal "abortion clinics" to prevent state jurisdiction? Are there similar precedents of the Federal government legalizing something against the wishes of the states?

Comment: Related, though there wasn't a definitive answer there:  [If Roe is overturned, could Congress still protect abortion rights?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/75123/if-roe-is-overturned-could-congress-still-protect-abortion-rights)

Comment: Also, concerning Federal legislation that went against the wishes of the states, the Voting Rights Act springs to mind.

Comment: One the one hand, asked and answered in [If Roe is overturned, could Congress still protect abortion rights?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/75123/if-roe-is-overturned-could-congress-still-protect-abortion-rights). On the other hand, there are other possible grounds, which may not be out of the imaginative question. For example, the HIPAA privacy rule arises from a fix-up of the tax code (tax and spend clause); the ADA is justified by referring to the 14th Amendment. I think the question as is invites baseless speculation.

Comment: No, the question is as answerable as virtually any other. Any question about what the law permits or discuss "invites speculation" about what a court might say, but that doesn't make the speculation baseless.

Comment: @bdb484 Indeed, the fact that the highest court in the land is (possibly) about to overturn one of its own decisions on this very topic demonstrates that there can never be a definitive answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If Roe is overturned, could Congress still protect abortion rights?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/75123/if-roe-is-overturned-could-congress-still-protect-abortion-rights)

Comment: @Robert Columbia
 while related, the linked question asks about one specific proposed law and its effects. That is not IMO a duplicate of this briader question.

Answer (score 24):

The federal government has the power to regulate interstate commerce, the current definition of which is incredibly broad -- certainly broad enough to include the provision of abortions.

If it were challenged, the government would likely rely on [*Gonzales v. Raich*, 545 U.S. 1 (2005)](https://casetext.com/case/gonzales-v-raich). In *Gonzales*, two patients who used medical marijuana as authorized by state law challenged the federal government's laws prohibiting the use of medical marijuana. They argued that because they were growing their own marijuana, because it never left the state, and because it was for personal, noncommercial use, it was outside Congress' authority to regulate interstate commerce. But the Supreme Court rejected their arguments, holding that Congress could use its Commerce Clause authority to enact health-care laws regulating access to marijuana and pre-empt contradictory state health-care laws.

The federal government's case for regulating abortions would be event stronger than its case in *Gonzales*: First, because obtaining an abortion is typically a commercial enterprise; it is likely covered by insurance, and even if it patient isn't charged, someone is likely paying the doctor money to perform it. Also, abortions more obviously implicate interstate commerce because patients frequently travel from state to another to obtain one, because clinics order supplies and services from outside the state, and because they rely on instrumentalities of interstate commerce (highways, telephone lines, the Internet) to do their job.

Indeed, as far as I know, every court to consider the issue has concluded that regulating access to abortion is a straightforward application of the Commerce Clause. *See, e.g.*, [*Terry v. Reno*, 101 F.3d 1412, 1418 (D.C. Cir. 1996)](https://casetext.com/case/terry-v-reno) (“Violent and obstructive activity outside abortion clinics adversely affects interstate commerce in reproductive health services. In enacting the Access Act, Congress did not exceed its Commerce Clause power.”); [*Cheffer v. Reno*, 55 F.3d 1517, 1520-21 (11th Cir. 1995)](https://casetext.com/case/cheffer-v-reno) (“Congress found that doctors and patients often travel across state lines to provide and receive services, id.; in other words, there is an interstate market both with respect to patients and doctors. In addition, the clinics receive supplies through interstate commerce. ... Congress' findings are plausible and provide a rational basis for concluding that the Access Act regulates activity which "substantially affects" interstate commerce. Thus, the Access Act is a constitutional exercise of Congress' power under the Commerce Clause.”); [*U.S. v. Wilson*, 73 F.3d 675, 688 (7th Cir. 1995)](https://casetext.com/case/us-v-wilson-537) (“the Access Act may be viewed as a direct regulation of interstate commerce and confirms once again that the Act is well within Congress's power to legislate under the Commerce Clause.”).

Reacting to *Dobbs*, then, Congress could write a law finding that existing state laws pose a threat to the interstate markets for providing and receiving reproductive services, and then rely on those findings to say that the only limits on abortion are X, Y, and Z, and that states may not impose any additional restrictions.

Comment: Like this one? https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/3755/text

Comment: Just like that.

Comment: I think Rick Smith's [answer on politcs](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/72949/18373) is more probable than this.

Comment: And as we just saw, this is a court that really cares about precedent!

Answer (score 6):

Could Congress, by preempting state law, make abortion legal in all 50 states? The only thing thing that really matters is whether the Supreme Court would uphold such a law (and it would inevitably end up in front of the Supreme Court). I think it's unlikely, given the current conservative majority on the Court, that it would be upheld.

It appears to be well-established that Congress has broad power to *ban* things, as long as the Supreme Court is persuaded that those things are a form of "commerce" (and the bar for this is not high). The constitutionality of the [Partial-Birth Abortion Ban Act of 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial-Birth_Abortion_Ban_Act) was upheld by the Supreme Court in [*Gonzales v. Carhart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonzales_v._Carhart). The Opinion of the Court stated that Congress has the power under the Commerce Clause to "regulate the medical profession". [*Gonzales v. Raich*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonzales_v._Raich), involving production and consumption of cannabis where no actual commercial activity occurred, and [*Wickard v. Filburn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wickard_v._Filburn), involving wheat production where no actual commercial activity occurred, are earlier cases on the same theme.

But does anyone think that Congress could make cannabis *legal* in all states, preempting state laws to the contrary? Maybe for *medical* purposes, they could: at least one federal district court has concluded that state bans of FDA-approved prescription drugs are preempted by Federal Food, Drug, and Cosmetic Act. See [*Zogenix v. Patrick*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=951773783965811573). But it is much harder to imagine that Congress could make *recreational* cannabis legal in all states and that the Supreme Court would uphold such a law against constitutional challenges. You could try to argue in front of the Court that the exact same power to regulate commerce that allowed Congress to ban cannabis in all states should, by the exact same reasoning, allow Congress to make cannabis legal in all states. I think the odds of this approach working with the conservative majority on the Court are pretty slim.

Or, to give another hypothetical example, could Congress use its Commerce Clause power to make prostitution legal in all states, preempting state laws to the contrary?  Again, I think you'd find that the conservative majority on the Court would take a dim view on this. And while abortion is in no way comparable to prostitution, conservatives think that abortion is even worse, because it kills an unborn child. So I think it's unlikely that Congress could successfully preempt state-level bans on abortion.

If the Court had a different ideological composition, it would be really hard to say what outcome would be more likely. There is not a lot of relevant precedent.

Comment: I can imagine the Congress having the power to prevent interference with a person traveling to participate in the commerce of another state for cannabis or abortion, or to preempt criminal statutes prohibiting the telehealth prescription or mailing of cannabis or abortion pills from another state. The receiver may still suffer consequences but it might be able to be mitigated by heightened mail privacy statutes.

Comment: Abortion is not recreational. It can't be done without a medical license, IIRC. Well, except by pill in the 1st week[s] or so, but the relevant medication is Rx-only in the US. So comparison with recreational cannabis seems pretty off-base.

Comment: Frankly the most bulletproof decision SCOTUS could make is to overturn Roe based on the 10th amendment, which is what a lot of Republicans are clamoring for. Then it would be really difficult for Congress to pass any legislation in that regard, without padding/packing SCOTUS first, that is.

Comment: @Fizz Abortion is clearly not recreational, but that's not the issue here. The federal government might be able to overrule state governments on the issue of whether a drug is safe and effective enough to be a legal medication. It is much harder to argue that Congress can preempt a *moral* judgement by state legislatures such as "getting high is inherently bad" or "killing fetuses is inherently bad".

Comment: Yeah, but that's only so if they go for a 10th amendment decision, like I mentioned.

Comment: This answer seems to engage primarily in speculation about how justices' ideology would influence their decisions. To the extent it discusses the law, it's also pretty far off base. Congress very plainly has the authority to pre-empt state laws that interfere with interstate commerce. See, e.g., *Schollenberger v. Pennsylvania*, 171 U.S. 1 (1898) (overriding state ban on oleomargarine); *Railroad Co. v. Husen*, 95 U.S. 465, 473-74 (1877) (overriding state ban on Mexican cattle).

Comment: @bdb484 The cases you cited predate *Wickard v. Filburn*, and Congress was plainly acting to regulate *actual* interstate commerce. In the modern era, Congress can outlaw almost anything by calling it interstate commerce, but can they also preempt state bans on almost anything using the same power? I don't think it's so straightforward to say that the answer is yes.

Comment: @bdb484 I also don't think that speculating about how ideology will affect decisions is inappropriate here; we've never seen Justice Barrett vote to reverse *Roe* and *Casey* before, but it was reasonable to predict that she's going to do so. In the absence of clear precedent on an issue, the justices will obviously tend to be influenced by the question of whether they personally think it's absurd that the constitution would require a particular outcome. That Congress could preempt state bans on prostitution, for example, seems too absurd for any "conservative" justice.

Comment: Your argument seems to be built on an assumption that abortions aren't commerce. But women give insurance companies money to cover abortions, insurance companies give that money to hospitals to provide abortions, and hospitals give that money to doctors to perform abortions. We're pretty obviously into interstate commerce territory.

Comment: @bdb484 No, I'm not assuming that abortions aren't commerce. I think, for example, that if Congress amended the ACA to require insurers to cover abortion and to preempt any state laws to the contrary, there would be no constitutional obstacle.

Comment: @bdb484 But I think there are limits, and the Court would draw a line somewhere, even if only because their personal views would lead them to conclude that taking this principle to its extreme would result in absurdities. This is why I mentioned the example of prostitution. Prostitution is clearly a commercial activity; does that mean Congress can make it legal in all 50 states? I think the Court would draw a line somewhere before that.

Comment: @bdb484 Regarding what reasoning they would use, I'm not going to claim that I know the answer. Perhaps they would look at the "objective" of the state law: is it primarily to prevent activities that are subjectively immoral, or is it primarily to regulate the commercial *aspect* of the activity? On the other hand, when the situation is reversed, and Congress is banning something, the Court would not apply such an analysis. This might seem inconsistent, but it's certainly not my decision to make.

Comment: All of this is why this is a low-quality answer. You're predicting the court would reach Decision X, but it would do so for personal reasons and that you can't identify a coherent legal argument to support it. That doesn't really tell the reader anything about the law.

Comment: @bdb484 agreed; the question is about valid bases, not about predictions and definitely not about politics.

Comment: I think that I did explain the basis on which the federal government could attempt to defend a law (if one existed) that preempts state bans on abortion. I *also* happen to think that SCOTUS would reject this argument.

Answer (score 4):

### Purse Strings

The standard way to get near uniform state laws (or lack thereof) on an issue is to dangle bags of money in front of the states.  The states all have the power to set their legal driving and drinking ages, as well as their speed limits, to whatever they see fit, but yet these values were remarkably uniform for a time, with most driving ages being 16, most drinking ages being 21, and most highway speed limits being 65.  Congress has at various points used federal funding to make this happen; though some have been repealed or altered by this point, or had states decide they didn't wish to participate, resulting in a greater spread of values in the present day.  But in any case, by making certain funds contingent upon meeting conditions such as minimum ages, they can persuade states to meet those conditions to save themselves money.

There are SCOTUS-imposed limits on how strong this "persuasion" can be.  The requirements have to be meaningfully related to what's being funded and the goal thereof (so putting abortion access requirements on environmental funding won't work), and it can't make up so large a portion of the state budget that it becomes impossible to pass up the funding.  Where the line on this is vague, I think it was last placed around .5%.

On average, States spend about [9-10% of their budget](https://www.urban.org/policy-centers/cross-center-initiatives/state-and-local-finance-initiative/state-and-local-backgrounders/health-and-hospital-expenditures) on healthcare, with 9-10% of that coming from federal grants.  So approximately 1% of state budgets are predicated upon federal healthcare fundings.  Make at most half of those (on average) contingent upon meeting some minimum access to abortion care, and you may have yourself a SCOTUS-approvable way to constitutionally persuade, but not mandate, states to pass uniform sets of laws.  Some states may forgo this, and clearly with the current SCOTUS there's no telling what prior precedents they'll happily strike down, so there's no guarantees, but it otherwise creates financial pressures by offering alleviation of state budget issues.

Answer (score 1):

The Secretary of Health and Human Services wrote a letter to hospitals regarding the emergency treatment, required by the EMTALA act of 1986. According to the letter:

"As frontline health care providers, the federal EMTALA statute rotects your clinical judgment and the action that you take to provide stabilizing medical treatment to your pregnant patients, regardless of the restrictions in the state where you practice." The letter is dated July 11, 2022. It provides support for emergency abortions that might not be allowed under state law.

See the letter at: https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/emergency-medical-care-letter-to-health-care-providers.pdf

There might be other regulations or directions that could be made under Federal regulations of health insurance, health insurors, or hospitals that serve Medicare or Medicare patients.

All these tools are indirect and limited in scope. It also seems that many such proposals would be struck down by the current courts.

Answer (score -6):

The most unassailable way (other than Constitutional Amendment) to make abortion legal, is oddly enough, to make it illegal.  If Congress makes it illegal after a certain point, then any attempt to make it illegal BEFORE that point, would run into the Supremacy Clause.  This would allow a law that applied to all 50 states (and the territories) to trump any local laws.  The more specific they cover, the more difficult it would be to argue they hadn’t carved it out as their own area to decide.

Comment: So, what's your proposal? That congress makes it illegal after 10 months?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: that’s exactly how the Supremacy Clause and immigration is treated.  States can’t make any laws in regards to immigration.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: and OSHA? https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/505/88.  Federal law trumps State, going both ways if they so desire.

Comment: @jmoreno These are areas where Congress has express authority of regulation that can be used to hedge out state laws.  Congress can regulate interstate congress, and when imposing regulations on an industry it is able to exclude states from imposing their own regulations, even if they are in harmony with federal ones.  Because Congress wishes to exclude the problems of regulations varying by state, they can exclude state action.  But the power to do that comes from the commerce clause (or whatever), not the Supremacy Clause.  Supremacy Clause is a rule of decision, not a power.

Comment: That said, I think I see what point it is you were trying to get at in your answer, which seems more possible to me now.  I'm not sure a federal ban is necessary to then exercise a bar on state level bans.  But any such bar would not have its power derived from the Supremacy Clause, but from exercising legitimate federal power under another clause.  The Supremacy Clause just tells the courts that the federal law wins out as long as it is exercising a constitutionally granted power, not that it bars state actions; the law itself says or doesn't say that.